# How to check if variable is present in a table? TCL

Tags: mysql, sql, tcl

I'm very new to this language and need some help. I want pass/send email variable and see that if it is present in a database table?

```
'proc: TEST::TestingFunc {ArrayName}{
 upvar #0 $ArrayName Param
   if {[info exists Param(data)]} {
        set email $Param(data)
      }
}'
```

Comment: pls make more clear questions.

Comment: Please add some more details.

Comment: And Googing "tcl mysql" did not give any result how to connect to MySQL with TCL?

Comment: What came up when you googled 'sql check if value is in table'?

Comment: Hi, i edited my post. Once making the connection still have not able to figure out how to send value and see if it matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, I just need the formatting capabilities to write this comment. It's not quite clear what you are asking about or what you want to do. The code you posted seems mostly OK if you want to check if there is a member named `data` in a given associative array, and get its value. There are a couple of errors in the code: it should look something like this

```
proc TEST::TestingFunc {ArrayName} {
    upvar #0 $ArrayName Param
    if {[info exists Param(data)]} {
        set email $Param(data)
    }
}
```

For this to work, you also need to have created a namespace called `TEST`.

Beyond this, I'm unsure what you want to do. What do you mean by "pass/send"? Is the "database table" you are talking about the associative array, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Thanks for the answering. I need to check in a database table if a certain email address exists. This function is an addition in an application. The application has a email field and i need to send its value to the table and check if that value exists in the table. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to have a database where one of the fields is an email address, and to search the database to see if a given address is present in one of the records in the database. But I still need to know what kind of database it is, and how it is arranged, at least roughly.

Comment: Ah, Well it is a simple SQL database, for example it has a table name: "Persons" and column name of email which is a string value.

Comment: How are you interfacing the database to your script? I am somewhat familiar with `sqlite`; there is also Tcl ODBC. (BTW, local evening is upon me, so I might not see your response for some hours.)

Comment: I have some reference code and the way it has been done in it is `set query "select from $::TS::database.xxxx where email = '$email'`. I assume that would match the data? PS . I understand and i appreciate you helping me.

Comment: Are there any `package require` lines in your reference code?

Comment: Yes there is `package require http` and `package require tls`

Comment: Is there nothing that indicates what kind of database connection it is using?

Comment: No it does not mention what type but i have been able to peform what i originally set out to do.  By doing this:  `proc TEST::TestingFunc {ArrayName} {
    upvar #0 $ArrayName Param
    if {[info exists Param(data)]} {
        set email $Param(data)  set query "SELECT email FROM xxxDB Where email = "$email"  set result [::TEST::database_do_query $query]  if{[llength $result > 0}{return true}`
    }
}`